# Understanding Apache Spark RDD task serialization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I am trying to understand how task serialization works in Spark and am a bit confused by some mixed results I'm getting in a test I've written.

I have some test code (simplified for sake of post) that does the following over more than one node:

```scala
object TestJob {
  def run(): Unit = {
    val rdd = ...
    val helperObject = new Helper() // Helper does NOT impl Serializable and is a vanilla class
    rdd.map(element => {
      helperObject.transform(element)
    }).collect()
  }
}
```

When I execute `run()`, the job bombs out with a "task not serializable" exception as expected since `helperObject` is not serializable.  HOWEVER, when I alter it a little, like this:

```scala
trait HelperComponent {
  val helperObject = new Helper()
}

object TestJob extends HelperComponent {
  def run(): Unit = {
    val rdd = ...
    rdd.map(element => {
      helperObject.transform(element)
    }).collect()
  }
}
```

The job executes successfully for some reason. Could someone help me to understand why this might be? What exactly gets serialized by Spark and sent to the workers in each case above?

I am using Spark version 2.1.1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could someone help me to understand why this might be?

In your first snippet, `helperObject` is a local variable declared inside `run`. As such, it will be closed over (lifted) by the function such that where ever this code executes, all information would be available, and because of that Sparks `ClosureCleaner` yells at you for trying to serialize it.

In your second snippet, the value is no longer a local variable in the method scope, it is part of the *class instance* (technically, this is an object declaration but it will be transformed into a JVM class after all).

This is meaningful in Spark for the reason that *all worker nodes in the cluster contain the JARs needed to execute your code*. Thus, instead of serializing `TestObject` in its entirety for `rdd.map`, when Spark spins up an Executor process in one of your workers, it will load `TestObject` locally via a `ClassLoader`, and create an instance of it, just like every other JVM class in a non distributed application.

To conclude, the reason you don't see this blowing up is because the class is no longer serialized due to the changes in the way you've declared the type instance.

Comment: Thank for the thorough reply, that makes a lot of sense now. To further clarify, can you help me to understand how big or small each task that executors run are? Does the term "task" refer to one or more RDD operations (map, filter, etc), or does it refer to running all RDD operations (ie the full "pipeline") on a subset of the dataset?

Comment: @simonl A task is the smallest unit of execution. Generally you can think about each operation, such as a `map`, `filter`, etc as a single task. But in reality, Spark optimizes these transformations into a single task execution. How does Spark know which tasks it can "squish" together? It usually does these for what we call "narrow transformations", which are basically lazy functions which yield back an `RDD`, until it reaches a "wide transformation", which is a transformation bound by shuffle of the data.

Comment: @simonl I hope that previous comment makes sense, kind of difficult to explain everything in ~ 500 characters.

Comment: For the most part yes, thank you - your comment led me to this: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-transformations.html#narrow-transformations

If you have any additional recommendations on resources for deepening understanding of Spark at this level, would love to check them out.

Comment: @simonl That is a great resource to learn. What I did was to dive into the Spark code base and look at the various classes which control distribution of work. If you'd like to do that, start by looking at the `DAGScheduler`. Also, I'd recommend the "High performance Spark" book.